# Does each instance of a JavaScript class have a copy of method bytecode?

Tags: javascript

Say I instantiate 100 copies of this class

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    // lots of lines of code
  }
}
```

Will all 100 copies have in-memory copies of the bytecode for bar(), or is there one in-memory copy of bar() and all the instances have a function pointer to it?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have anything called bytecode.

Comment: If you're *instantiating* the class, you're not copying anything. In fact there's still only a single function, `Foo.prototype.bar`. Your question would be much more interesting in the context of closures, where multiple different function objects have the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of the `bar` method will share the same reference, an easy and quick way to see that is with the `===` operator, for example:

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    // lots of lines of code
  }
}

const a = new Foo()
const b = new Foo()

console.log(a.bar === b.bar)
>>> true
```

Comment: This is correct. The `===` operator is a shallow value comparison operator. Except for strings and numbers this operator compares the address of objects. So when applied to two functions it compares the address in RAM both functions are located at. If two similar looking functions are located at different RAM address the `===` operator would return false

Answer (score 1):

There will only be one copy of `bar` in memory, and usually only one reference to it as well.

Instances of Foo will have each have a reference to their shared prototype object (Foo.prototype), which has the reference to `bar`.